# Black screen after loading SceneView, using Scenform, into a fragment

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality, sceneform

I am working on a project that will have a 3D model viewer in one fragment. In order to do so, I decided to use sceneform. I have encountered a problem with SceneView, after trying to display it, in my tab fragment.

Everything is done according to examples and sceneform documentation, but `sceneView` display black screen, regardless of the colour I am assigning.

Here is scene loader

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_open_gl, container, false);
        sceneView = vw.findViewById(R.id.scene_view);
        return vw;
    }
```

And fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OpenGL">

    <com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView
        android:id="@+id/scene_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Crimson"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding pausing and resuming sceneview, along with the fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sceneView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            sceneView.resume();
        } catch (CameraNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too bad I found it only now.. Had same issue implemnting scene form as a UI component into RN and wasted a ton of time on it. For anyone see's it in the future you must `sceneView.resume` if you don't have `onResume` method to override in your implementation! Kamil you could have saved my life.. Sadly I stumbled on this only after figuring it out.. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: very much helpful answer.

Comment: i have tried this but this is not working for me can you please take a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125461/sceneform-sceneview-always-black-in-fragment

Comment: I was having the same problem I changed the background colour to white and placed the node and it started working perfectly

Comment: The issue for me was that changing color didn't do anything (I placed the node as well), it remain black because sceneView wasn't loading/showing on screen at all. Since you could change the color to white  and it actually worked, I'd assume it was node/camera placement problem

Comment: This fixes the black screen, but the FrameLayout has a memory leak when calling ```sceneView.pause()```